# How to do always the same things just before 'return' when a function has a lot of 'return's?

Tags: c++

I've a big function which allocates 2 arrays in the heap memory and returns many times in many different places. I would like to make the function call `delete[]` for my 2 arrays whenever she returns, without having to write `delete[]`s before each `return`.

```
int function(int a)
{
    size_t heap_arr1_len{100};
    int* heap_arr1{new int[heap_arr1_len]};
    
    size_t heap_arr2_len{200}; 
    int* heap_arr2{new int[heap_arr2_len]};
    
    //I was thinking of something similar to:
    struct at_return{
        ~at_return()
        {
        delete[] heap_arr1;
        delete[] heap_arr2;
        }
    } at_return;

    /*...............
    .................
    ......return 0;*/
    /*...............
    .....return 10;*/
    //ecc.
}
```

but with a compilation-time error i've figured out that a struct can't access the local variables of the function which is contained in.

What would you do in order to avoid to having to write `delete[] heap_arr1;`, `delete[] heap_arr2;` each time before each `return`?

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.  It will clean up after itself.  [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) is one of C++'s best features.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead. You could also use a class as a scope guard to cleanup in its destructor,.

Comment: If you don't want to use the std, you can create a simple wrapper for your array, which will handle construction and deletion in ctor and dtor.

Comment: @AdrienGivry: WHY?? `std::vector` does exactly that!

Comment: @TonyK: "if you don't want to use the std"

Comment: @AdrienGivry: That's like saying "If you don't want to use `C++`, you can just program it in assembly language."

Comment: By the way, this is one of the use cases for `goto` (in `C` at least).

Comment: i've written some functions that deal with binary files to / from arrays. i can't use vectors. when i'll learn how to do the same with vectors, i'll use them, but for now i just want to go ahead with arrays

Comment: There is also std::array if you don't want to use a vector.  Or use std::unique_ptr.

Comment: The proper way of doing this without a `std::vector` is harder than learning how to use `std::vector`. :) It's like saying *"I don't know how to use my left hand yet, so for now I want to do push-ups with a single hand"*.

Comment: Isn't this literally what `try..finally` blocks were invented for?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError There is no `try..finally` in C++. You may have confused it with C# or Java or JavaScript. The C++ version of` finally` is RAII.

Comment: _I've a big function_ Can you see a way to split it up?  From what you say, it's already proving to be a maintenance headache, and it may well do so again some time down the line.

Answer (score 4):

Don't allocate memory manually using `new`, use `std::vector` instead:

```
size_t heap_arr1_len = 100;
std::vector<int> heap_arr1(heap_arr1_len);
```

Then you don't need to worry about `delete`.

---

But using a destructor like this is in fact a great idea, **assuming** no suitable wrapper class exists. This trick is known as a [scope guard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ). And here's a [working implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063110/2752075).

It could be useful e.g. when dealing with C libraries, which can't provide classes with destructors. You could write a reusable wrapper class with a destructor, or you could use a scope guard as an ad-hoc solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <memory>

int function(int a)
{
    size_t heap_arr1_len{100};
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> heap_arr1{new int[heap_arr1_len]};

    // Etc
}
```

If you need the underlying pointer for your file reading/writing functions, use heap_arr1.get().

Comment: This also has the benefit of freeing the memory if an exception is thrown, which the manual `delete[]` does not handle.

Comment: I prefer `std::make_unique`, to have a no-brainer strict rule of never calling `new`/`delete` manually (outside of custom containers/smart pointers).

Answer (score 0):

I use a `can_continue` method so there is only one entry and one exit (MISRA rule).
First set a Boolean variable:

```
bool can_continue = true;
```

The pattern then becomes:

```
if (can_continue)
{
   // do some work
   // set can_continue to false to return unexpectedly
}
```

It may not be the fastest code, but it meets the criteria for one entry and one exit.